# Create new contact using flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, vcf-vcard

So I have this "Save Contact" button in flutter web and I want when clicking on it either save a vcf on the device laptop/android/ios or open an add new contact default form in the device and add these infos in it I tried some packages but they support only android and ios not web and I also tried to make the vcf manually but I couldn't get the path because path provider only support android and ios

So How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use this package -  [contacts_service](https://pub.dev/packages/contacts_service)

you can save all necessary user information

Comment: I tried this one but it only works on the mobile app not the web app

Comment: I just saw that it only works with mobile applications, I've never seen anything related to the web